CSS pointer events and spacebar
When I add  pointer-events:none; to video (just to temporarily disable controls), if focus is on play button, spacebar still triggers play.

is this intended behavior?

what would be the cleanest to prevent this?  (possible without javascript?)


To replicate, on page load, click play video to get focus, wait few seconds for pointer-events then use spacebar.


setTimeout(function(){

document.getElementById('video').classList.add('disabled')
},4000)
.disabled{
  pointer-events:none;
}
<video controls id="video">
<source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4">
</video>




What system are you running on because I cannot reproduce this (using Windows11 Edge, tried both in an SO snippet and as raw code)?

@AHaworth You need to press on the play button on the video, and then press the spacebar right after that. Me here on Windows11 Edge, too.

@AHaworth Windows 10, Chrome

What comes to my mind is also removing controls when disabling the video:
document.getElementById("video").attributes.removeNamedItem("controls");


In the end I decided to remove focus:  document.activeElement.blur();
